# iOS : Creating a 3D Compass

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, 3d

I want to make a 3D metal compass in iOS which will have a movable cover.
That is when you touch it by 3 fingers and try to move your fingers upward the cover keeps moving with your fingers and after certain distance it gets opened.Once you pull it down using 3 fingers again, it gets closed. I have attached a sketch about what I'm thinking.
[image: my compass animation]

Is it possible using core animations and CALayers? Or would I have to use OpenGL ES?

Comment: Nice work on the sketches!

Comment: Maybe the gamedesign SA forum would have better input.

Comment: Thanks @jrturton :) One of my friends did it for me, mine one was not that smooth. ;)

Comment: Where can I find that forum? @ja72

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim [At gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

First you should obviously create a textured 3d model in app like 3Ds Max or Maya. Then export it to some suitable format. The simplest one is OBJ (there are lots of examples about how to load it). There are two options about animation:

1. Do animation manually by rotating the cover object. It's probably the easiest way to do that.
2. Create animation in you 3D editor and then interpolate between frames. By doing this you can get much more realistic view. However in this case OBJ format is not suitable, but COLLADA is. To load it I suggest to use Assimp library.

And if you don't need some advanced interraction another option is to use pseude 3D: just pre render all the compass animation frames and use that animation applied to 2d texture.

Comment: Wow!Great explanation! Thanks! Meanwhile I made an image of the cover in photoshop and made the desired animation using CATransform3DRotate method.All I need now is to incorporate it with something 3D. I must try 3DS Max. What about blender? And also tell me, If I have a 3D model of the cover, then when I rotate it using same code I do now,is it going to look like the way I sketched? I mean is there any need of defining the 3D frames in the animation that I didn't need in my current 2d image.

Comment: One more thing, I have to interact with it.Like- **1**.User touch 3 fingers , it gets unclasped. **2**.He then continues to drag the touch and so the cover keeps opening.Once he reached a certain point it gets fully opened. **3**. He touches 3 fingers again and continues to pull it downward it gets closed. Sorry if I'm not clear. @ Max

Comment: You really don't need to use 3D at all. Just create 2d animation (i.e. apply different texture images that you get from 3ds max rendering). I have almost no experience with Blender so I can't tell anything useful about that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit? An example would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.